# What questions to ask to determine how to design Search functionality

Tags: user-behavior, search, user-research

I am trying to define how a website search should be designers for a website that has products, articles, recipes and other general content pages.

The answer seems obvious, have a faceted result page for each content type. However, this seems too simple.

What questions should I ask to inform the solution further? 
or... how should I approach search design in general?

Thanks!

Comment: Who are you asking? Do you mean you're going to users to discover what tasks they're trying to accomplish on your site?

Comment: If you're going to attempt to surface all of these content types via a single search box, you need to think carefully about the possible use-cases.  You don't want a search for "cup" to return every recipe (for example).  Recipe search is typically very specialized, and a universal search box will generate a lot of noise results unless you consider only, say,  the recipe title and 1-3 main ingredients.

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of different search patterns, where each suites a particular goal. Peter Morville & Jeffery Callender wrote a great book about them called Search Patterns - Design for Discovery [http://searchpatterns.org](http://searchpatterns.org/)

> The design of search is a tricky business. **Each project is unique**.
>
> For starters, we must select research methods that fit the context.
>   Unobtrusive field observation is rarely practical, since search is
>   generally ad hoc. But we can surely draw upon other ethnographic
>   techniques, including interviews, questionnaires, and diary study.

You started by creating a design, i.e. `The answer seems obvious, have a faceted result page for each content type`, but surely you start by firstly understanding your users and discovering what they want to find.

So everything begins by understanding the find-ability goals of the user. I cannot tell you the questions you might need to ask because I don't know your context, but I imagine these might start you off:

- Are they looking for something specific?
- Are they browsing to find something suitable?
- Do they even know what they are looking for?

> Search is a multidisciplinary collaboration of design, engineering,
>   marketing and management.